# 504 Gateway Time-out after executing SQL query

Tags: linux, mysql, phpmyadmin

I executed a SQL query via phpmyadmin, to delete all tables of my test database, after a failed import. First there was a pop-up saying "Loading" in the middle of the screen, but I was getting sceptical after it stayed for >1 hour, so I closed the tab and opened it again.

However, it loaded and loaded and then I got "504 Gateway Time-out", this was yesterday at 18:00 European Time. So I went home and tried it again today at this moment. But I still get 504.

It seems like the databases are still working though, since my websites are working as expected. I have ssh access to the server, is there a way to solve this problem, without having to restart the entire MySQL Engine?

There are a few production sites live.

The database was only about 200 MB. MySQL 5.7 is used.

The load is at `1.01 / 1.08 / 1.10`

Comment: I'd start by checking the logs of php and mysql.

Comment: Unfortunatelly my hoster deactivated logs.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the support, they said that a cronjob was running which should normally run overnight, but it did not finished. They killed it and now everything is alright again.